# cant get past 3rd level of json with jq query

Tags: json, jq

this is a snippet of json. i am trying to get the value of:

> [data][allBlocks][edges][node][date][epoch][lastBlock][id]

using jq from the command line. i can query as far as [edges] but for some reason I cant get the data for [nodes] or anything past that.

`jq .data.allBlocks.edges` is as far as I can get down the tree. ive looked at the jq manual and i dont really understand the query parameters. nothing i put after edges results in any output its always some kind of error.

```
Formatted JSON Data
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "allBlocks":{ 
         "pageInfo":{ 
            "hasNextPage":false,
            "hasPreviousPage":true,
            "startCursor":"190519",
            "endCursor":"190521"
         },
         "totalCount":"190522",
         "edges":[ 
            { 
               "node":{ 
                  "id":"27921be509a1336ceaa164cee00cda91c2719a1c0148239433e233ae1bb09c9b",
                  "date":{ 
                     "slot":"16338",
                     "epoch":{ 
                        "id":"60",
                        "firstBlock":{ 
                           "id":"917927a503ed3d9be307dd18f27680c11cb0c405a834c316e3920c7ed8b4e2e8"
                        },
                        "lastBlock":{ 
                           "id":"27ee50d49eacef10d9ccbfd3c29d09a1aea8268901776085c835ba34f607185b"
                        },
                        "totalBlocks":"1475"
                     }
                  },
```

Answer (score 1):

`.edges` is an array, so using your approach, you would have to take that into account, e.g. by writing:

```
.data.allBlocks.edges[].node.date.epoch.lastBlock.id
```

Another of many alternatives you might wish to consider would be to use `..`, e.g.:

```
.. | try (.lastBlock.id) // empty
```

Or:

```
.. | objects | .lastBlock.id // empty
```

Comment: aweseom thank you. i was confused by jq's [] for arrays and i thought i had to put the rest of the path inside the [] like edges[.node.date...]